# Comment box is misaligned with button on 2019 Moderator Election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

On the [2019 Moderator Election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11), when adding a comment, the "Add Comment" button and the little blue "help" link overlay the text area.

I'm using Windows 10 and I'm seeing this on the three major browsers I use.

Firefox:
[image: The Add Comment box overlaps the text box by about .5cm, as does the "help" link on Firefox]

Chrome:
[image: Same, but on Chrome]

And for completeness, Edge:
[image: Same, but on Microsoft Edge]

I'm seeing the same bug using the mobile browser Chrome for Android as well, plus a weird shrink of my own comment:

[image: Same issue, on moblie chrome]

Comment: MSE report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323830/alignment-issue-in-election-add-comment-section

Comment: Sidetracking a bit, but Davy M - have you ever submitted a bug report about your profile picture? It's three Dilbert panels - the mini version (displayed on your posts) truncates it to be 1:1 aspect ratio, keeping only the middle panel, but the larger version (visible on your profile) shows the whole image, but is now squashed so all three panels fit in a 1:1 image. [Side by side comparison here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKUla.png). It's always felt... weird to me. It affects other users, but less obviously (their images are usually close to 1:1 aspect ratio).

Comment: @WaiHaLee Nope, I never considered it a bug because I intentionally set up the image that way so that my general icon showed the middle panel, yet the profile had the full comic. If I wanted to make it look nice, I could crop the image myself, then put the full image in my About Me section, but I've always just been too lazy to make that change.

Comment: hah! "for completeness, Edge"

Comment: Only now see that this also reports the tiny text, just like I just did: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380950/my-own-comment-on-the-election-is-sized-differently?noredirect=1#comment675343_380950

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks for the heads up. Since my bug report is focusing on the comment box, I decided to post my recreate as an answer to your bug report so that there's another data point there.

Comment: @coldspeed Especially now that Edge is just Chrome-in-a-dress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

[As Martin notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380890/comment-box-is-misaligned-with-button-on-2019-moderator-election-page/380912#380912), the root cause here was the use of content-box sizing on the page when the comment form was designed around [border-box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Rather than adding yet another inconsistency to trip up future work, the solution I chose was was to rework the entire page to play nicely with border-box mode, dropping the old table-based layout and borrowing heavily from the layout now used on question pages. This also allowed enabling responsive layout for the page, which will hopefully address [some of the complaints](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380950/my-own-comment-on-the-election-is-sized-differently) around trying to read nominations on mobile devices.

Answer (score 5):

Adding

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to the textarea element fixes the issue on desktop view.

Full fix in `primary.css`:

```
.comment-form > form textarea, .comment-form > form 
div[contenteditable="true"] {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    height: 5em;
    width: 100%;
    resize: vertical;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* This is the only added line */
}
```