# My own comment on the election is sized differently

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election, mobile-web, design

I left a comment on the nomination of one of the nominees on the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1). Visiting that page on mobile, responsiveness enabled, produced a rather odd sight.

Browser: Chrome 72.0.3626.105 
OS: Android 9.0.0.195 (Huawei)

[image]

Comment: Damned an over leak of the "StackOverflow for ants".. The official annonce is in 25 days.

Comment: just asking, a ton of meta topics about mod election, with a ton of comment, just trying to have the quickest path to the comment. And no repro Android 4.4 to 7.1.2 with  Lastest chrome.

Comment: I think it's a new feature auto-detecting if comments are important/welcoming.. available in 6-8 something

Comment: For a measly $10 you can take part in our Premium Comment Experience, with enlarged font size and comment permalinks! Try it today!

Comment: @AndrasDeak There is actually a bug, though :, the button for trying is too small to  be visible

Comment: The problem is with delete button for sure. Removing it from DOM fixes it, but I can't figure out why. Even changing the element type to "div" fixes the issue.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Don't you mean $9.99 / month? I think a service like that needs a snappy name, maybe they could call it the expert package, and it could be for the whole Stack Exchange network; I got it, Experts Exchange!

Comment: @xdtTransform This feature-initiative was introduced by the worlwide optician association for the marginal comission of 6-8 $ per SO-user that needs help with their eyesight after reviewing their comments..

Comment: We just pushed out a set of updates (including actual responsiveness support) for election pages. Mind checking to see if that resolved this problem? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear, resolved for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also reproduced, here on Chrome (72.0.3626.96) for Android 9.

[image: Same issue, on moblie chrome]

However no repro on Puffin (7.7.8.31160) for Android 9.

[image: Comment appears normally]

---

Good news!

> We just pushed out a set of updates (including actual responsiveness support) for election pages. Mind checking to see if that resolved this problem? Thanks! – [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380950/my-own-comment-on-the-election-is-sized-differently/380958#comment675967_380950)♦

And lo and behold:

[image: Comment appears normally on chrome now]

Looks like this one is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now.

Comment: Not sure multiple answers repro'ing the issue are particularly useful.

Comment: @DavidG hmm.. are they even _"answer"s_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yeah, I thought about writing that too. Either way, more than one is not useful.

Comment: @DavidG, this comes from another post if DavyM, where he also noticed this. To combine the info in one place he posted his findings (which were posted before my Q here) as an answer here.

Comment: @DavidG As per [What's the right approach for a “me too” report of a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308412/7795130), "If the bug was reported more recently than a year and is still not resolved then gather all of your evidence and post a detailed answer with your reproduction of the issue." As Luuklag mentioned, I had already encountered this issue, but my bug report was about something else, so I brought my recreate here, and to make sure it was different from the original recreate (also chrome for android), I showed a failure to recreate on the same device so that it's more exact.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, they are, as per the question linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 8):

I can find it present also in another browser and OS. My configuration is completely different from yours:

Device: Galaxy Note8
OS: Android 8.0.0
Browser: Samsung Internet

All my comments appear in small letters, similar to your screenshot. Any other comments have standard font size.

Since I could see the same problem present also on another website, I think this is rather an issue in browser engine. Because what [Samsung Internet](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/introducing-samsung-internet-for-developers-6c3a3be42f72) may have common with [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_for_Android) is the underlying Chromium + Blink engine (this is visible in linked articles).

**I would say this is a currently present defect in browser engine. No issue in the site itself.**

Comment: Interestingly, I don't see it in mobile firefox on android. Then again responsiveness itself seems broken for me, I see the non-mobile interface no matter what I do. Perhaps it's only broken for people with working responsiveness.

Comment: @AndrasDeak – answer updated: maybe the Chrome and Samsung Internet have common underlying technology.